# java.lang.ClassCastException: optional int32 count is not a group

Tags: parquet-mr

I want to see contents of a `parquet` file. I ran the following command but got error `java.lang.ClassCastException: optional int32 count is not a group`.

`manu@manu-VirtualBox:~/parquet-mr/parquet-tools/target$ java -jar parquet-tools-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT.jar cat ~/test/part-00000-3d55da69-71e8-462f-a478-68363b7af1a1-c000.snappy.parquet`

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update your parquet-mr. This is the result of a bug, [PARQUET-1527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1527), which is already fixed both in the master branch on github and in the latest release candidate for 1.11.0.